# How to import/export the tracking setting of a policy

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-rule-engine

I've noted from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa547590.aspx) page that policy isn't exportable to a bindings file.

Is there another way to import/export the tracking setting?

Comment: It certainly isn't obvious.  It is not in the binding file or the policy file exported from BizTalk.  The BizTalkOM shared library only knows about the Port Tracking Types and not the Policy ones. So I think is short the answer is No, you can't import or export those.

Comment: Did you ever find a way of doing this?

Answer (score -1):

Try looking at the following [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577374.aspx) which describes the method by first exporting only the policy using BTSTask into an MSI and afterwards using BTSTask to import them again.

> BTSTask does not provide a specific command for importing policies;
>   however you can use the ExportApp command of BTSTask to selectively
>   export only the policies in an application that you want, including no
>   other application artifacts. Then you can use the ImportApp command to
>   import the .msi file into an application in a different BizTalk group.
>   This is the approach described in this topic. When you do this, the
>   policy is automatically imported and published in the BizTalk group
>   and added to the specified application.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I seem to only get the policy, but not the tracking settings ??

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but isn't it so that the tracking settings come in the binding file?

Comment: The tracking settings for the ports, schemas & modules in the application are in the binding files, but not for the Policies.